# Metro server does not run and not connect to the app in React Native

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

When I run `react-native start`, emulator and Metro Server does not connect to each other and when I hit `r` to refresh app, it say no connected app ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi i had this same problem and was scratching my head for a while, it seems there was a security update in Android 9 which disabled cleartext by default.

adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your manifest in the `<application>` tag fixed the issue for me:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      ...
```

I found the fix in this Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23380